# What's The Point of AspNetRoleClaims in Asp.net Identity Core?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-2.1

I am using asp.net core 2.1 and I more leaning to use roles vs User Claims as my requirements for the site are pretty small.

However I don't understand why there is a AspNetRoleClaims table.

Say I have 2 roles

Admin

General

What would go in AspNetRoleClaims? Everything I put in that table has to be hooked up to 1 Role so it's not like I can share claims around.

Edit

The link does still not clear up what it is for.

```
A role is something assigned to a user.
Eg. Jane is an admin.
A claim is something claimed by a user.
Eg. Jane's date of birth is 1990-10-1.
A role-claim is a claim claimed by a role.
Eg. Admins have access to the dashboard.
```

on the surface this makes sense but like I said 1 role claim is hooked up to 1 role.

So what is the point of checking if the admin can have access to the dashboard as the "claim" that would say "access to the dashboard" will always be linked to "admin"

If AspNetRoleClaims and AspNetRoles would be a many to many relationship it would make alot more sense.

Comment: It’s really just for bulk-assignment of claims to a user within a specific role.

Comment: Do you mean bulk assignment into AspNetUserClaims?

Comment: please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50401190/asp-net-core-identity-use-aspnetuserclaims-or-aspnetroleclaims

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Asp.net Core Identity Use AspNetUserClaims or AspNetRoleClaims?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50401190/asp-net-core-identity-use-aspnetuserclaims-or-aspnetroleclaims)