# ASP.NET Core 6 web app with Identity - Ind. Accounts. How can I add a role and add 2 users to that role?

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, asp.net-identity

Ok, I remember back in regular ASP.NET 4 (before .NET Core - 2015 ish) it was not this convoluted to add a user to a role. But now I found it to be very difficult.

Using Sqlite database, and all the scaffolding and account creation works great. Even imported my contact subscriber list and it seamlessly created the CRUD - awesome.

Now I only need to restrict this page to Admins only, which I did this and works -- no access. I am on the step to add an Admin role and add a user to it.

After reading and trying code from many sites I find myself here for some direction.

Also I see a role and role claim which is confusing..

[image: ASPNetModels]

[image: DbSet]

[image: Options]

---

Ref: [How to create roles in ASP.NET Core and assign them to users?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42471866/how-to-create-roles-in-asp-net-core-and-assign-them-to-users)

This may work if I knew where to put this for it to find the proper references.

```
private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
private readonly RoleManager<ApplicationRole> _rolesManager;
```

Not sure where the ApplicationUser and ApplicationRole is coming from.

Comment: I'd suggest starting with [Introduction to Identity on ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio) and working through all of the articles in that section. Create an empty ASP.NET Core project and go through the steps to do all the scaffolding, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have correctly configured Identity in your application with something similar to the following

```
builder.Services
    .AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>(options =>
        options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
      .AddEntityFrameworkStores<WebApplication2Context>();
```

(in your case, `IdentityUser` is probably going to map to your `AspNetUser` class and `IdentityRole` would be your `AspNetRole` class, though I'm not sure where you got those classes or whether they properly inherit `IdentityUser<T>` and `IdentityRole<T>` - if they don't, you've gone down a dark and scary road...)

Once that's done (and you've applied all the EF Core migrations, etc. to get your database correctly built), you can do something like this to add a role and add a user to it

```
@page
@model IndexModel

@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@inject UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager
@inject RoleManager<IdentityRole> _roleManager

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";

    await _roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole("Admin"));
    await _userManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityUser("foobar") { Email = "foo@bar.com" });

    var newUser = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync("foobar");
    await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(newUser, "Admin");
}
```

If you're not sure your existing `AspNetXxx` classes are correct or correctly map to the related Identity classes, I'd suggest you start over and use the default implementations as much as possible. You can read about [Identity Model Customization in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/customize-identity-model?view=aspnetcore-6.0) to learn about the model and how all the different tables work together.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to "link" your "MyPolicyName" to your MVC.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-6.0#apply-policies-to-razor-pages

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;

namespace AuthorizationPoliciesSample.Pages;

[Authorize(Policy = "AtLeast21")]
public class AtLeast21Model : PageModel { }
```

...

Because of this "string-matching-magic" I would create a single-source-of-truth class.

public static class MyPolicyNames
{
public static string AtLeast21PolcyName = "AtLeast21PolicyName";
}

and refer to this const in both places.  And eliminate future "where are the magic-strings" scavenger hunts.

=============

So you are using a Policy, but your "policy rule" is to then check a Role.

Should you be just using Role?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/roles?view=aspnetcore-6.0

I guess M$ says its "ok"

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/roles?view=aspnetcore-6.0#policy-based-role-checks

Comment: The authorization works, it is locked down but I need to create a role and add my user to an admin role to see the page.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50572725/214977

Comment: This is why my PERSONAL naming rule is to put the word "To" in the mapping/linking table name.     dbo.DepartmentToEmployeeLink tablename for example.  they all starting running together after a while.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42471866/how-to-create-roles-in-asp-net-core-and-assign-them-to-users  Do you have code to add a user/role and user-to-role link anywhere?

Comment: dosent look like it, figured that aspnet would handle internally. Or at least have a template CRUD page for User Management. I looked at the examples and they all seem to reference  _roleManager and I have to clue what the context of this is.

Comment: private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
    private readonly RoleManager<ApplicationRole> _rolesManager;

Both ApplicationXXXX cant be found.